# How to fit the image in the filling region?

Tags: image-processing, filling, version-12.1

Consider the following fillings:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage","Peppers"}]

Plot[1,{x,0,1},Filling->Axis,FillingStyle->PatternFilling[image,ImageScaled[1]]]
Plot[1-x,{x,0,1},Filling->Axis,FillingStyle->PatternFilling[image,ImageScaled[1]]]
```

How do I fit the image in the region so it doesn't repeat and also is not cropped rectangularly? (Basically, I want to change the aspect ratio and size of the image to fit it in the filling region)

The first plot should display the full image while the second should display the diagonal (lower triangular) half of the image.

Is there an option or some configuration to do this?

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that the effect of `PatternFilling[]` is easily affected by the setting for `AspectRatio`.